# genfromtxt file returns filling values as -1

Tags: numpy, genfromtxt

I'm trying to use genfromtxt to extract a csv file that contains missing values such as 'na' and '-'
I am required to look for the minimum value in the list of data, but the missing values got returned as -1.

this is my code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('median-resale-prices-for-registered-applications-by-town-and-flat-type.csv',
                     skip_header=1,
                     dtype=[('quarter', 'U7'),  ('town', 'U50'), ('flat_type', 'U10'), ('price', 'i8')], delimiter=",",
                     missing_values=['na','-'], filling_values=[0])

min_price = np.min(data['price'])
print(min_price)
```

and this is what i have in return

-1

i have also tried isnan()

```
print("Original data: " + str(data.shape))
null_rows = np.isnan(data['price'])
print(null_rows)
nonnull_values = data[null_rows==False]
print("Filtered data: " + str(nonnull_values.shape))
```

however, python did not perceive the na and - values as isnan
Original data: (9360,)
[False False False ... False False False]
Filtered data: (9360,)

is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: without the missing/filled parameters what values do you get in the `price` column?  Without a sample of the file it is hard to offer much of a diagnosis.  I'd have create a sample based on what I imagine yours is like.

Comment: How do you know the filled values are -1?  Did you actually compare `data` with the csv?  Or are you just assuming that's what's happening from this min?

Comment: quarter,town,flat_type,price
2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,1-ROOM,na

2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,2-ROOM,-

2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,3-ROOM,172000
2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,4-ROOM,260000
2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,5-ROOM,372000

Comment: im assumed that what's happening since the returned value is +1, i tried changing to the price dtype to f8 but now both the max and min got returned as NaN

Comment: The sample would be easier to use if added to the question.  In the comment newlines are lost.   Show your `data` with that sample.  `np.nan` is a float, so can't appear in a `i8`.  Don't assume anything.  I haven't used fill and missing_values much, so really need to pull up the docs.  And experiement.

Answer (score 1):

With the sample, adapted from the comment:

```
In [26]: txt1="""quarter,town,flat_type,price
    ...: 2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,1-ROOM,na 
    ...: 2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,2-ROOM,- 
    ...: 2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,3-ROOM,172000 
    ...: 2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,4-ROOM,260000 
    ...: 2007-Q2,ANG MO KIO,5-ROOM,372000"""
```

Accepting that last field as floats (no fill stuff):

```
In [27]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt1.splitlines(),
    ...:                      skip_header=1,
    ...:                      dtype=[('quarter', 'U7'),  ('town', 'U50'), ('flat_type', 'U10'), ('price', 'f8')], delimiter=",")

In [28]: data
Out[28]: 
array([('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM',     nan),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM',     nan),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000.),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '4-ROOM', 260000.),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '5-ROOM', 372000.)],
      dtype=[('quarter', '<U7'), ('town', '<U50'), ('flat_type', '<U10'), ('price', '<f8')])
```

`genfromtxt` normally uses `nan` for values it can't parse as floats.

For integer, it apparently uses -1 instead:

```
In [29]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt1.splitlines(),
    ...:                      skip_header=1,
    ...:                      dtype=[('quarter', 'U7'),  ('town', 'U50'), ('flat_type', 'U10'), ('price', 'i8')], delimiter=",")

In [30]: data
Out[30]: 
array([('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM',     -1),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM',     -1),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '4-ROOM', 260000),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '5-ROOM', 372000)],
      dtype=[('quarter', '<U7'), ('town', '<U50'), ('flat_type', '<U10'), ('price', '<i8')])
```

After some fiddling, I got this to work.  The key was to use a single value of `filling_values`, not a list.

```
In [54]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt1.splitlines(),
    ...:                      skip_header=1,
    ...:                      dtype=[('quarter', 'U7'), ('town', 'U50'), ('flat_type', 'U10'), ('price', 'i8')], 
    ...:                      delimiter=",", 
    ...:                      missing_values=['na','-'], 
    ...:                      filling_values=-999)

In [55]: data
Out[55]: 
array([('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM',   -999),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM',   -999),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '4-ROOM', 260000),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '5-ROOM', 372000)],
      dtype=[('quarter', '<U7'), ('town', '<U50'), ('flat_type', '<U10'), ('price', '<i8')])
```

Looking at the code (via `[source]` in the docs), I see we can use `dict`, specifying different values for different columns.  Thus

```
missing_values={3:['na','-']}, 
filling_values={3:-999})
```

There are more details in the code than in the documentation.  I haven't used these values much, so each time I have learn more.

### edit

In today's question you seem to have forgotten all that you learned here. `data` is a structured array.  With `f8` you get `nan` for the missing values, not `-1`.  And you attempt to treat the array as a list of tuples.  Why not continue to treat it as a structured array?

The `price`field:

```
In [104]: data['price']
Out[104]: array([    nan,     nan, 172000., 260000., 372000.])

In [106]: mask = np.isnan(data['price'])   # or test against -1 for ints
In [107]: mask
Out[107]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
```

Use the mask to select, or "delete" elements from the 1d array:

```
In [108]: data[mask]
Out[108]: 
array([('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM', nan),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM', nan)],
      dtype=[('quarter', '<U7'), ('town', '<U50'), ('flat_type', '<U10'), ('price', '<f8')])

In [109]: data[~mask]
Out[109]: 
array([('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000.),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '4-ROOM', 260000.),
       ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '5-ROOM', 372000.)],
      dtype=[('quarter', '<U7'), ('town', '<U50'), ('flat_type', '<U10'), ('price', '<f8')])
```

But here's a list based approach:

```
In [110]: alist = data.tolist()
In [111]: alist
Out[111]: 
[('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM', nan),
 ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM', nan),
 ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000.0),
 ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '4-ROOM', 260000.0),
 ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '5-ROOM', 372000.0)]

In [112]: [i for i in alist if not np.isnan(i[3])]
Out[112]: 
[('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000.0),
 ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '4-ROOM', 260000.0),
 ('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '5-ROOM', 372000.0)]
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping, i changed the price dtype to f8 and used np.nanmax and np.nanmin to find the maximum and minimum values, and it worked fine