# How to remove tuple from an array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, delete-row

The array is a 1D array:

[('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '4-ROOM', 450000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '5-ROOM', 582500)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', 'EXEC', 800000)]

I would like to remove the tuples containing the '-1'

i'm currently using the del function

```
datacopy = np.copy(data)
print(datacopy)

for i in datacopy:
    if i[3] == -1:
        del i
    print(datacopy)
```

but i end up getting repeats of the same array:

[('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '4-ROOM', 450000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '5-ROOM', 582500)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', 'EXEC', 800000)]
[('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '4-ROOM', 450000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '5-ROOM', 582500)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', 'EXEC', 800000)]
[('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '1-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '2-ROOM',     -1)
('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '4-ROOM', 450000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '5-ROOM', 582500)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', 'EXEC', 800000)]

what i would like to get in return is

[('2007-Q2', 'ANG MO KIO', '3-ROOM', 172000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '4-ROOM', 450000)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', '5-ROOM', 582500)
('2022-Q1', 'YISHUN', 'EXEC', 800000)]

Comment: What's `data.dtype`?  Did you get this from a csv file with genfromtxt?

Comment: It looks like your putting statement is INSIDE the for loop…

Comment: In your previous question you loaded `data` with `genfromtxt` with a compound dtype.  That is a structured array, not an array of `tuples`.  You access fields by name.  `data['price']` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976722/genfromtxt-file-returns-filling-values-as-1

Comment: You get repeats because you `print(datacopy)` each iteration of the loop.  `del i` deletes the variable `i`, which is the iteration variable.  It does not delete that item from the array.  You can use `del alist[2]` to remove an item from a list, but `data` is an array.  `del` does not work there.

Comment: I edited my previous answer to show how to select specific items from a structured array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
newList= [x for x in datacopy if x[3] != -1]
```

Here, x will be each of your tuple, and *if x[3] != -1* will work as filter regarding your condition

Answer (score 0):

Either to use

`filtered_data = [tuple for tuple in data if tuple[3] != -1]`

Or

`filtered_data = filter(lambda x: x[3] != -1, data)`